# Moving payment on Woocommerce page template

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce

I have a Woocommerce shop that I need to customize a bit. I need to move the payment options into the customer details div (and remove it out of the order_review div). My theme is already using a two column layout for the checkout, so that billing&shipping fields are on the left side, and order review table and payment are on the right side. I can move they payment methods underneath the billing with this

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_checkout_payment', 20 ); 
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'woocommerce_checkout_payment', 20 );
```

But this also moves the order button. How can I ONLY move the payment methods into the customer-details div? I need to achieve a layout like here:
https://static.konversionskraft.de/2015/10/ringly_b2.jpg

Comment: What you can do is play around with the template files payment.php and form-checkout.php. I have archived the same with changing them.